# How to claim experience when not directly paid by a company/organization

Tags: resume, applications, freelancing

So, I'm helping my mother build her resume up after being a stay at home mom for a long while.

Some background: she worked as an administrative assistant / clerical assistant with Glaxo Smith Kline and Burroughs Welcome up until she had me. She then started staying home. As my dad took on a sales position, she helped out as much as she could from home with administrative work. She did a lot of work in excel, word and publisher in helping my father get clients including making very large databases, handling finances, mailing clients, etc. Though, this was for my father and never directly for the company. She needs to find a way to prove her experience without claiming employment, as she wasn't employed. **Could she call this freelance work? She recently stopped doing this for my father in July 2016 when he switched positions; she did this for around 18 years lol. If not what could she call it? It would be a tremendous blow to have unlisted experience in administration for that long.**

Trying to integrate this at all costs so that she can appear qualified for the admin jobs she is applying for. This is not 'milking' it, she was solely responsible for my father becoming number 1 in sales in the world for his company. As a result of her experience she is extremely competent in database management and microsoft office in general. She also has a major and minor from the prestigious UNC at Chapel Hill.

Never even thought of dealing with a situation like this all help is appreciated. I wish she gave her planning a bit more thought as to how she could actually be credited for the great work she did.

-Charles

Comment: Was your father an exec?

Answer (score 5):

It makes no sense to try and claim a *job* that didn't actually exist. But it makes perfect sense to claim the *skills/experience*.

Trying to say "I was a Personal Assistant" makes no sense. Just as saying "I was an Educator" or "I was a Budget Coordinator" or "I was a Purchasing Agent" or "I was an Interior Decorator" would make no sense. There's nothing wrong with saying "I was a stay at home Mom". That's hard stuff!

Mom wasn't employed. Don't mislead the interviewer to think that she was - interviewers tend to look down on that sort of thing.

Instead make sure the resume, and in particular the cover letter, emphasizes her skills and experience, rather than made up jobs.

Writing something like "I helped my Sales Rep husband by performing a lot of the administrative work. I eventually became proficient in Excel, Word and Publisher. I created and maintained very large databases, I handled company finances, and I handled all of the client mailings. I'm a wiz at Office, MySQL and Adobe Dreamweaver" can lead to great interviews where Mom can discuss and demonstrate her full abilities.

It sounds like Mom has everything she needs to get and succeed in a great job, without needing to lie or exaggerate.

Answer (score 0):

She was certainly your father's personal assistant, and that probably should be her job title (*)(**). Give the description of what she did for your father under that job title and the impact on your father's performance. Let her mention that she was unpaid during the interview. Don't mention that she was unpaid anywhere on her resume. The resume is meant to list her duties and her accomplishments - keep it that way and don't add any extraneous information such as her position being unpaid.

In fact, she should mention that her position was unpaid during the interview to keep HR from taking off after her with demands of pay stubs and W-2 forms. Have your father provide a letter as supporting evidence if HR is asking for this kind of documentation.

She is going to have to come across as very confident and just as competent during the interview and convince the interviewers that they want to have her on the team.

(*) Don't call it "freelance" - that's a horrible idea. If you have her do that, then you'll put her in a position where she has to explain why she negotiated for a position with no compensation. It was work, and it was unpaid, that's all there is to it. Lots of spouses put a ton of work into their significant other's startup or business without any compensation. Not being compensated does not make the work experience any less real or the work any less skilled. Quite a few males have the nasty habit of  not considering unpaid work as work. Call it male privilege.

(**)  I recommend that you have your mom's resume be reviewed for accuracy by one of the workforce centers that your state's Department of Labor runs. I have to warn you that some workforce centers are better than others. Pick a workforce center that is targeted toward helping job seekers who are working at the professional level and who specialize in helping people reintegrate the workforce.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - I guess you weren't there when a ton of educated women who had been housewives got themselves in the workforce in the 1970s and the 1980s. They had to do all sorts of contorsions to get their first entry-level corporate job - that's how the functional resume came about. I am confident that if she will handle her interviewers' questions about her qualifications with aplomb.

Comment: Sometimes you have to exaggerate a bit to get your first professional job.  Not advocating out - right lying, but stretching the truth a bit to get your foot into an entry level gig is not unreasonable IMHO. @VietnhiPhuvan

Comment: @MisterPositive - I don't believe in exaggerations - exaggerations never worked for me not least because I'd be raising expectations unnecessarily, expectations for which I could be held accountable. I don't need to give myself this kind of headache. It's not only about her getting the job, it's also about keeping the job after getting the job. Back in 2000, I hired a young National Guardsman as entry level tech because of all the techs we interviewed, he was the only who told the truth: "I don't know anything".

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan  I am aware of all the obvious stuff you stated in your comment above.  I agreed with and upvoted your answer.  Your suggesting she embellish upon what she actually did over the years.  Its my belief she will have to in order to get back into the work force.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - What makes you think that the OP is lying about his mother's work experience? I don't get agitated when people lie about their experience and skills - when I find out that they lie, and sooner or later I will find out,  they are out the door.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - So far as I am concerned, she held the job of personal assistant for her husband for 18 years. And I expect her to have at least the skills of a personal assistant for having worked as a personal assistant for 18 years. Whether she has that skills set is verifiable. On another note, there are probably quite a few Asian women who manage ethnic restaurants for their husbands - the only thing they get out of their gig is that they get to sleep with the boss. The fact that these women don't get paid doesn't mean they didn't manage their husbands' restaurants.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - As for verifying that she actually performed as a personal assistant, I'd ask her "tell me some of the challenges you faced down over the years as your husband's personal assistant" - If she really faced down challenges, her answer will have a ring of truth.

Comment: Thanks for your honest contribution. Your profiling of her is quite accurate. I originally put it on her resume, but with all the negativity spewing about I figured it's better to be safe than sorry and just take it out. It's a shame, she's a wiz with Office, MySQL and Adobe Dreamweaver because of it. I suppose she should have thought everything through better. She never anticipating having to go back to work but things change. Oh well, stuff happens.

Comment: @CharlesKenney - I don't think she did anything wrong by supporting your father's sales effort from home. As a sales person, your dad is a bit of an entrepreneur and she supported that entrepreneur. I did work on a consulting basis when I was a grad student at Columbia Engineering for a chemical engineer who ran his own firm. His wife did the accounting for him, didn't draw a salary and she told me that I was making more than her because all she was getting out of it was sleeping with the boss - I'll tell you, British immigrants work just as hard as other immigrants  :)  (Cont)

Comment: @CharlesKenney - The fact is, you mom did the job, because that's how she acquired that skills set. Neither you nor she should allow yourselves to be intimidated by anyone who says otherwise if in fact, she did the job. The fact that her work was unpaid is a separate matter from whether she did the work and acquired that experience and skills. Just make sure that her experience and skills are relevant to the positions she is going for.

Answer (score 0):

1: "Part Time Admin Support to Mr. Blah Blah, Sales Rep for ABC Co" followed by tasks/skills

2: If she helped your grandpa from 18 yrs, his co-workers/boss probably know her or remember her. She could call them up and explain the situation and ask ABC Company how she should list her experience helping their employee. They might be able to give her a reference as a volunteer or something

3. Functional resume template/format, and same description from #1